# Table of Contents Page with Dynamic Page Numbers

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Master Report with multiple sub-reports that generates a PDF. It will be printed by our clients, so it needs to have page numbers and a TOC to reference where the particular sub-report resides in the printed report.

SSRS doesn't have the ability to create a TOC with pages.

What is the best work-around for this problem?

Estimating the page number that a particular sub-report starts on from page size, row size, nb of rows etc, isn't an option, because the reports have different fonts and row sizes depending on the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found an adequate solution that I've built a POC on - and it works.

Its a two pass approach, using custom external assemblies. First rendering sub-reports to populate a Table of Contents table, and then running the master report and displaying the TOC results on the TOC page, and after that the sub-reports agaain.

Here's the [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/echarran/archive/2005/11/07/489797.aspx) that got me going.

Regards,

Jason